# The Lerch Phi Function and a possible Mathematica Bug [Solved]

Tags: sequences-and-series, mathematica, wolfram-alpha

The Lerch Phi Function is defined as

$$\Phi(-s, \alpha, \nu) = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-s)^k}{(k+\nu)^{\alpha}}$$

Now, in my special case I have $\alpha = 1$, hence it does simply reduce to

$$\Phi(-s, 1, \nu) = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty}  \frac{(-s)^k}{(k + \nu)}$$

Clearly if I put $\nu = 0$ the series shall be infinite.

But when I compute it with Mathematica (Wolfram Serious Mathematica software, not Online Alpha) it says that

$$\Phi(-s, 1, \nu) = -\ln(1+s)$$

How is this possible?

**EDIT**

There are also other problems related to that. For example setting $\nu = -1$ and Mathematica says

$$\Phi(-s, 1, -1) = 1+ s\ln(1+s)$$

Which is actually not true, since by its definition (both it starts from $k = 0$ or $k = 1$ there is a point in which the series is infinite).

Comment: It looks as though Mathematica starts at $k=1$.  This will give you what you seek.

Comment: @SimpleArt The problem is that the definition on Wolfram Documentations says it starts from $k = 0$. Sure $k = 1$ would solve the problem... If it's not a bug, then there is an error in the documentation form.

Comment: That is probably the case we are seeing.

Comment: Perhaps you should try a couple of other values to deduce if it starts with $k=0$ or $k=1$.  I don't happen to have mathematica, so...

Comment: What in the world?$$1+s\ln(1+s)=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-s)^{k+1}}k?$$I'm not sure, and this could just be a hunch, but maybe Mathematica removes all the undefined points from the series.  That is, maybe it interprets $\frac10=0$ in a series.

Comment: Be careful not to mix up [LerchPhi](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LerchPhi.html) with [HurwitzLerchPhi](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HurwitzLerchPhi.html)

Comment: @polfosol You're right, but there is no confusion in that!

Comment: See the first few lines under [details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LerchPhi.html)

Comment: @SimpleArt o.O I just noticed... "where any term with  is excluded" lol. Wow, how could I miss that? Thank you! That shall explain every doubt!

Comment: What a strange function...

Comment: @SimpleArt Indeed! But I love it haha! Thanks for making me notice that DETAIL! I consider the problem solved

Comment: Yup, cheers for finding the answer in the simplest of ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [reference](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LerchPhi.html), we have

$$\Phi(-s, \alpha, \nu) = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-s)^k}{(k+\nu)^{\alpha}}$$

for $\Re(\nu)>0$.  For $\Re(\nu)\le0$, we have

$$\Phi(-s, \alpha, \nu) = \sum_{k = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-s)^k}{[(k+\nu)^2]^{\alpha/2}}$$

where any term $k+\nu=0$ is eliminated.

References:

---

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LerchPhi.html

Comment: Huh, you know what's funny?  I was reading about this function yesterday, and I actually noticed all this and was like "Wow, what a strange function!" only to forget and rediscover the next day.

Comment: Haha! By the way, try to color the last link in RED, so that people will immediately read the strangeness of the Lerch phi! And thanks again.

Comment: @AlanTuring There we go, that should be more obvious.